# Create Git Repo with New Project in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio 2017, there used to be an option when creating a New Project to "Make a new Git Repository with Solution", or something similar.

I can't seem to find the option in Visual Studio 2019. Has it been removed? I was thinking maybe it requires an extension?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This option has been removed.

See section *Remove unnecessary choices* in [*Redesigning the New Project Dialog*](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/redesigning-the-new-project-dialog/).

Alternative option is to add to source control option on the status bar (or start with a `git init` before, or clone from remote<sup>*</sup>).

---

<sup>*</sup> Eg. new (blank) repository in GitHub, Azure DevOps, ...

Comment: Who thought this was a better idea over at Microsoft??

Answer (score 30):

Yes, it's strange, isn't it... not being given the option to save your code to git, when you're creating a new project.

The solution is simple enough though - just click on the "Add to Source Control" item at the bottom-right of the Visual Studio 2019 window.

[image]

From there, you are given the option to "Push to Azure DevOps Services", or to a Remote Repository.

What is really cool about this first option is that this sets up everything you'll need in the Azure DevOps site, ready to add Continuous Integration, Pipelines, etc.

And, obviously, you can see the files from your new VS2019 in the "Repos" section of this website.

Comment: Worth nothing that this only works after you've saved / created a solution file. Opening a project outside of a solution, and immediately pressing this button (or File > Add to Source Control) does nothing - nothing happens whatsoever (vs2019). Pressing Ctrl+Shift+S to save everything will create the solution file if it doesn't exist and after that it will work.

Comment: I cannot see this option in my VS2019. Any idea?
Nevertheless, I have this option under menu bar File > Add to Source Control.

Answer (score 19):

After creating a new project, I found an option under the `File` menu called `Add to Source Control`. That worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

The process in Visual Studio 2019 is much easier. Follow the instructions as state above:

1. Click on Add Source Control (bottom right-hand corner).
2. Select Git
3. If you were logged into your Git account before, it will show up with the name of your solution as the default name for the app.
4. Enter other info and click 'publish'

You should be good to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

adding an add on like this might be a good solution: https://visualstudio.github.com/

This way, you can easily manage your visual studio project on Github.

Or, does this work? https://github.com/github/VisualStudio/blob/master/docs/using/publishing-an-existing-project-to-github.md

Comment: Unfortunately my project isn't on GitHub. I'm talking about a local git reop

Comment: Sorry I read Github... Would this be helpful : https://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/2019/04/02/using-git-in-visual-studio-2019/